Intersection of cosets in Frobenius group
Suppose that $G < S_n$ is a Frobenius group. Let $G_i$ be a point-stabilizer of point $i$.
Suppose that $i$, $j_1$, $j_2$ are distinct point.
$\textbf{Question:}$ Is there any elements $t\in G$, $t\not=1$ such that $G_it \cap G_{j_1} \not= \varnothing$ and $G_it \cap G_{j_2} \not= \varnothing$ at the same time?
$\textbf{My attempt.}$ $G$ is a Frobenius group, so if $G_it \cap G_{j_1} \not= \varnothing$ then there exists exactly one element of $G$ such that $G_it \cap G_{j_1} = \{g_1\}$.
Let $G_it \cap G_{j_1} = \{g_1\}$ and $G_it \cap G_{j_1} = \{g_2\}$. Now we can say that if $fix(g_1) = j_1$ and $fix(g_2) = j_2$ then there is a element $t \in G$ such that $fix(g_1t^{-1}) = fix(g_1t^{-1}) = i$. I think that fact can be useful if we want to say something about $t$. And here I stucked....

Have you tried looking for a small counterexample? Try $n=4$.

@DerekHolt Sorry, I'm not familiar with Frobenius group. Why can't we choose $t=id_{S_n}$? Do we assume that $t$ is non-trivial by default?

@ShuningZhang Why are you asking me?

@DerekHolt Sorry, because you said that there is a counterexample and I think you are familiar with Frobenius group. I don't know whether this question needs to be corrected or I made a mistake.

@ShuningZhang I am confused. Are you the OP Orel_Algebraist? I think that to avoid trivial counterexamples you should assume that $t \not\in G_i$.

@DerekHolt No, I'm not the poster. I just came across this post. Sorry, my English is not good, there may be a misunderstanding. I also think additional conditions need to be added.

@DerekHolt, sorry for inaccurate wording of the question. Of course, I'm interesting in case $t \not = 1$ (question was edited).

@DerekHolt, I tried small groups but nothing except trivial counter examples I have found. Also if $G$ acts like regular group the question has an answer that only trivial elements $t$ suite these conditions. So I'm trying to consider the case when there are some elements with fixed point (Frobenius groups).

Also if $t\not = 1$ then $g_1 \not = g_2$.

As I said in my first comment, consider the case $n=4$. There is only one Frobenius group in that case, namely the alternating group $A_4$.

@DerekHolt, In case $A_4$: $G_1 = \langle(2,3,4)\rangle$ and $G_1t \cap G_3 = {(1,2,4)}$, $G_1t \cap G_4 = {(1,2,3)}$, so $t=(1,2)(3,4)$. Do you mean that?

May be point-stabilizer should be cyclic groups?

Yes that is exactly what I meant. So your question is answered and the answer is that it is possible that such an element $t$ exists.

@DerekHolt, now the question that I'm thinking about is when does such element $t$ exists) (what are necessary and sufficient conditions for existing $t$ as in example...) :)

I used system of computer algebra sagemath and find something interesting. I tried all subgroups of $S_4$, $S_5$, $S_6$, $S_7$, $S_8$ and checked the property above. So all subgroups that suit it has cyclic point-stabilizer... or my code works wrong )
